# Is it possible to define interface getters for arrays of structs?

Tags: solidity, storage, solidity-0.8.x, interfaces, override

Given a state variable defined like this:

```
struct Segment {
    uint256 foo;
    uint256 bar;
}

Segment[] public override segments;
```

Is it possible to define a getter in an interface?

I've tried this approach but it didn't work:

```
function segments() external view returns (Foo[] storage);
```

And changing it to memory does not work either. Is this doable at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to define a getter in an interface for an array of structs. Below is a complete example illustrating this.

##### Interface Definition

Firstly, you can define the interface with the segments function and specify `Segment[] memory` as its return type.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.18;

interface IStructContract {
    struct Segment {
        uint256 foo;
        uint256 bar;
    }

    // If you want to only read a single Segment at a given index then in the interface you have to explicitly destruct the Segment struct's fields in the return type,
    // however you won't have to explicitly define a getter for this i.e. it'll be implicitly defined at compile time
    function _segments(uint256 index) external view returns (uint256 foo, uint256 bar);

    // If you want to return the entire _segments array you can declare a function with the following signature in the interface,
    // however you'll have to explicitly define this function as shown in the contract below
    function segments() external view returns (Segment[] memory);
}
```

##### Contract Implementation

In your contract, you can then implement this interface. Make sure to override the `segments` function and ensure the return type matches with the interface, i.e. in this case `Segment[] memory`

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.18;

contract StructContract is IStructContract {
    // You'll notice that the following variable is prepended with "_" as using "segments" gives a compile error indicating a name conflict with the "function segments()" below.
    // This is quite silly imo since solidity allows for function overloading and even if they had the same name the 2 functions would still have different signatures i.e.:
    // 1. function segments(uint256 index) external view;
    // 2. function segments() external view;
    Segment[] public override _segments;

    // Note: This function can be gas-intensive with increasingly large arrays
    function segments() external view override returns (Segment[] memory) {
        uint256 segmentsLength = _segments.length;
        Segment[] memory __segments = new Segment[](segmentsLength);

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < segmentsLength; i++) {
            __segments[i] = _segments[i];
        }
        return __segments;
    }

    // a simple setter for pushing a Segment onto the _segments storage variable
    function addSegment(uint _foo, uint _bar) external {
        Segment memory _segment = Segment({foo: _foo, bar: _bar});
        _segments.push(_segment);
    }

}
```

In this example, the contract `StructContract` correctly implements the `IStructContract` interface, and its segments function returns a memory array of Segment structs as expected.

Answer (score 1):

[Kamil Śliwak](https://github.com/cameel) showed me how to do this in the Solidity Matrix server:

```
struct Segment {
    uint256 foo;
    uint256 bar;
}

interface I {
    function segments(uint256 index) external view returns (uint256, uint256);
}
```

Also copy-pasting his answer:

> It is possible but it's not obvious.
>
> First thing is that getter functions never return the whole array. They return items instead and you need an argument to represent the index.
>
> The second is that due to historical reasons getters do not return structs directly (IIRC it's because they were introduced before structs had a well-defined representation in the ABI). Instead the struct gets unwrapped and you get its elements as separate return values.

Comment: Someone recommended me this answer a while back too. Though this returns values rather than the struct which was the original purpose.

Comment: you can still cast the struct when you implement or consume the interface.